# PHP variable in Javascript file

Tags: php, javascript

I have a variable I need to drop into a javascript file and can't seem to get any results. I've tried making the .js into a php and adding an echo but it doesn't work.

I have a file that calls this in it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/file.php"></script>
```

Inside of file.php I have this line

```
style: {
    color: '#<?php echo $_SESSION['colorOne']; ?>'
}
```

Everything works perfect when I replace the php with an actual color (#FFFFFF). I run into problems when I add the php.

Comment: `style:` is css , not javascript

Comment: Its part of a graphing script that uses it.

Comment: style is used for styling(css). Make your question clear

Comment: @Cherniv It may be a snippet from an `Object` literal. The `:` after `style` wouldn't really belong if CSS.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you're 100% , i need to drink some coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can emulate any content you'd like, even Images, PDF and Office files.

First, don't confuse Javascript with CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/file.php">
```

At the beginning of the `file.php`, make sure you start the session:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
.style: {
    color: #<?php echo $_SESSION['colorOne']; ?>;
}
```

If this does not work, you should debug if your session is init and working correctly, like make a new PHP file and put in `<?php session_start(); print_r($_SESSION); ?>`

Comment: Why would you use a session that you didn't initiate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call session_start() function before getting value of session, so, you need to put:

```
session_start();
```

At the top of that file.

Also, `<script type="text/javascript" src="/file.php"></script>` is for JavaScript file, not external style sheet, and last note is you can print the value without single quotes:

```
color: #<?php echo $_SESSION['colorOne']; ?>
```

Comment: SO definitely needs a "post at the same time buddy" badge. For answers posted within 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your file needs to be processed by PHP when it gets requested. When you are on Apache you need to add

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .MYFILEEXTENSION
```

to your .htaccess file. im not quite sure about nginx.

As a general idea, i've allways done this in the index.php file. Just print something into a global variable like

```
window.phpTransitionVariables = { ... };
```

with a script tag like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <? //print my php variables
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

write

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/css');
?>
```

on begin from the css file with php extension